# Entity Framework on SQL Server CE without driver install

Tags: wpf, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a WPF application using Entity Framework 4 and SQL Server CE database 3.5 and it's correctly working.

However I'd like to have this application to run on a machine with .Net Framework 4 installed but without the `SQL Server Compact 3.5` drivers. And no installer. Is it possible?

I have tried the following:

1. create a  section in the app.config

   ```
   <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
         <add name="DbEntities" 
              connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.Model1.csdl|res://*/Model.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Data\Database1.sdf&quot;" 
              providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.data>
         <DbProviderFactories>
             <add name="SQL Server Compact Edition Data Provider" 
                  invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe" 
                  description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition" 
                  type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
         </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
   </configuration>
   ```
2. add references to `System.Data.SqlServerCe` and `System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity` and allow local copy
3. build the application and copy it on a machine without SQL Server CE drivers installed. When it comes to create the data context I keep getting this error :

> System.ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

Am I losing time? Or should I just switch to SQLite?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to josemiguel.torres' answer, I check at [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx) detailling how to achieve this. However, I still have an assembly error.

```
"System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
```

So I had a look at [this other post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/05/12/troubleshooting-problem-with-private-deployment-of-sql-server-compact-3-5sp2-entity-dll.aspx) explaining how to fix this issue.
After adding some assembly binding:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.1.0-3.5.1.50" newVersion="3.5.1.50"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

It still doesn't work ... :|
Error message is similar :

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

File name: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'

I'm out of solution. Anyone?

**EDIT 2:**

1.I have uninstalled all the Microsoft "SQL Server Compact Edition" versions from my machine.

2.I checked the machine.config version : there is no entries in the DbProviderFactories section.

3.I downloaded the 3.5 SP2 drivers from [there](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5783) and installed the x86 package.

4.I check my machine.config (v4 x86) and the following entries has been created under the DbProviderFactories node:

```
<add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
```

Why is it 3.5.0.0 and not 3.5.1.50???

juste in case: my dev machine is on Win7 x64 and target machine is WinXP x86.

Comment: Check this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx

Comment: It looks better however I still have an assembly error.

Comment: Check your project platform is set to "x86". This issue could comes from your app.config. Check connection string.

Comment: It looks like it's an assembly binding issue as I detailed in my edit.

Comment: Are you using the 3.5 SP2 files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up with SQL CE 3.5 and switched to 4.0. It's working fine, thanks to [this article](http://erikej.blogspot.fr/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html).
Thanks Erik ;)

Answer (score 2):

Install 3.5 SP2, and modify the app.config as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ChinookEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Chinook.csdl|res://*/Chinook.ssdl|res://*/Chinook.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=C:\Users\erik.COMMENTOR\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SqlCeTest\Chinook.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 3.5" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.50, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly xmlns="">
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.1.0-3.5.1.50" newVersion="3.5.1.50" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Make sure to use the System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll and System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Private folder

Comment: For some reason the DbProviderFactories version don't match after I installed SP2. See edit 2.

Comment: And I'm using the files from the private subfolder

Comment: It should be 3.5.1.0 in machine.config - and make sure to install both the x86 AND x64 runtimes of SP2 (very important)

Comment: It's 3.5.1 in the machine.config located in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config" but 3.5.0 in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config". Is this intended?

Comment: No it should be 3.5.1.0 in both, make sure you install both the x64 and x86 runtimes (2 x MSI)

Comment: I have no idea why the versions aren't correct. I gave up SQL CE 3.5 and switched to version 4.