# MVC3 Code First Not Creating Database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I've been doing this Movies database tutorial for MVC3 with Code First, but when I try to access the `/Movies` page I get the error 
`"The network path was not found"`.

I don't think I missed any steps in the tutorial.

I created my Movie model

```
namespace Movies.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseData { get; set; }
        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I added the connection string as well

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Movies.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

In the tutorial the connection string is this, but it was giving me errors trying to create the controller so I found somewhere to change it to the one above, which allows me to create the controller fine but then get the network path error.

```
<add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Movies.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
new DbContext("MovieDBContext")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx
Did you try to emit at least a *select 1;* from your code?

```
  <system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="SQL Server Compact Edition Data Provider" 
           invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe" 
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition" 
           type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
  </DbProviderFactories>
```

See also [Entity Framework on SQL Server CE without driver install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300373/entity-framework-on-sql-server-ce-without-driver-install)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have forgot to add

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```